# Is there a way to recode variables based on multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following DF:

```
hhid <- c(106072900714,111033100205, 106072900714, 211030100502) 
hoso_new <- c(98, 95, 91, 92) 
quyen <- c(2, 3, 4, 6) 

HHID02 <- data.frame(hhid, hoso_new, quyen)
```

I would like to recode the hoso_new variable using the following conditions using dplyr language:

```
hoso_new=94 if hhid==106072900714 & quyen==2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: FYI dplyr isn't a language, it's just a package. Most things you can do with dplyr, you can do in R without dplyr

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Put your logic directly into `if_else`:

```r
HHID02 %>%
  mutate(
    hoso_new = if_else(hhid==106072900714 & quyen==2, 94, hoso_new)
  )
#           hhid hoso_new quyen
# 1 106072900714       94     2
# 2 111033100205       95     3
# 3 106072900714       91     4
# 4 211030100502       92     6
```

If you have multiple recodings (for the same variable) with different conditions, one might think to nest `if_else`, but usually a better approach (for readability) is `case_when`:

```r
HHID02 %>%
  mutate(
    hoso_new = case_when(
      hhid==106072900714 & quyen==2 ~ 94,
      hhid==111033100205 & quyen==3 ~ 999,
      hhid==111033100206 & quyen==3 ~ 998,
      hhid==111033100207            ~ 997,
      TRUE                          ~ hoso_new
    )
  )
#           hhid hoso_new quyen
# 1 106072900714       94     2
# 2 111033100205      999     3
# 3 106072900714       91     4
# 4 211030100502       92     6
```

From that, you can safely infer:

- The conditions do not need to be structured the same, ergo the 4th and 5th are different.
- Order matters, first found is used.
- There "should always" be a catchall, for declarative purposes if nothing else; the default action here is denoted with the `TRUE ~` action. If not specified, `NA` will be assigned (which is not what you want here).

Comment: Does this come close to addressing your question?